# Suppressing Facebook SDK UIAlertView in iOS

Tags: ios, uialertview, facebook-ios-sdk

I use the Facebook SDK for login in my App, I am on the newest version 3.2.1 and am having an issue with some of the errors the SDK throws.  For example (and I know this is an outlier case) if a user logs into my app, then while that session is open removes my app from their facebook, then logs out/logs in on my app Facebook throws a UIAlertView that says com.facebook.sdk error 5, then if the user logs in again it works just fine by re-requesting permissions as it should.

While this is a weird use case, it speaks to the larger issue of not wanting Facebook to communicate with my users through jibberish AlertViews, I would much rather detect the error and throw a proper alert that a user can understand.

Is there anyway (without re-writing the SDK, and yes I have filed a bug) to suppress all UIAlertView's from Facebook SDK, and throw my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When following the login procedures described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/): you have total control over the alerts. Facebook just passes you the error and you can chose what to display to the user, if anything.

Look at the Scrumptious sample app for an example.

If you have a specific case where the Scrumptious sample app throws an alert that you cannot control, please describe.

Comment: Wow, was looking for that answer forever, I had it set to display the error and didn't even notice.  Thanks!